# Django template rendering not giving expected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am rendering data from my views into my template, as follows:

```
<tbody>
    {% for item in lyrics %}
    <tr class='lyrics-table'>
      <td>{{item}}</td>
      <td>
      {% if item in user_flash %}
         <p>{{flash}}</p>
       {% else %}
        <p>xxx</p>
      {% endif %}
     </td>
```

`{{item}}` works as expected, but `{{flash}}` only gives the same value for every row, instead of the relevant value.

My views are as follows:

```
class SongVocab(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model= models.Song
    template_name = 'videos/song_vocab.html'
    context_object_name = 'song'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        from pymystem3 import Mystem
        m = Mystem()
        user_flash = Flashcard.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).values_list('question', flat=True)
        lyrics_list = models.Song.objects.get().lyrics_as_list()
        user_flash_ = [item.replace('\n', ' ') for item in m.lemmatize(" ".join(user_flash))]
        user_flash_clean = [w for w in user_flash_ if w.strip()]  ##removes empty strings
        lyrics_list_ = [item.replace('\n', ' ') for item in m.lemmatize(" ".join(lyrics_list))]
        lyrics_list_clean = [w for w in lyrics_list_ if len(w.strip())]
        user_word = list(set(user_flash_clean) & set(lyrics_list_clean))

        import icu # PyICU
        def sorted_strings(strings, locale=None):
            if locale is None:
                return sorted(strings)
            collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale(locale))
            return sorted(strings, key=collator.getSortKey)
        context['percent_known'] = ((len(user_word))/(len(set(lyrics_list_clean))))*100
        context['lyrics'] = sorted_strings(set(lyrics_list_clean),"ru_RU.UTF8")
        context['user_flash'] = user_flash_clean

        for word in user_word:
            flash = Flashcard.objects.get(owner=self.request.user, question=word)

        context['flash'] = flash.answer

        return context
```

I thought that using the `for` loop would let me get `flash.answer` for all words in `user_word`. In the example I'm testing, there should be two words, but I get just one. What am I doing wrong?

Models.py:

```
class Flashcard(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField()
    answer = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_shown_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    next_due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    difficulty = models.FloatField(default=2.5)
    consec_correct_answers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    objects = FlashcardManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    def number_of_questions(self):
        return self.question.count(deck=deck.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
for word in user_word:
    flash = Flashcard.objects.get(owner=self.request.user, question=word)
context['flash'] = flash.answer
```

`context['flash']` will hold the last `flash.answer`, because the last line is outside the for-loop (it has one indentation level less than the second line).

---

Did you perhaps mean something like this?

```
context['flash_list'] = []
for word in user_word:
    flash = Flashcard.objects.get(owner=self.request.user, question=word)
    context['flash_list'].append(flash.answer)
```

Comment: Thank you. This now gives me the whole queryset, but how can I now just show the relevant value in my template (instead of the whole queryset)?

Comment: @MeL I am not sure I understand this follow-up question. Could you add your models to the question so get a better picture of the situation?

Comment: I've added my Flashcard model. But perhaps it would be better if you take a look at my follow-up question here where I hopefully explain it a bit better: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62620352/13290801.